# Schema error when trying to upload xml file to RegData (FCA)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I know nothing about xml files or coding, so please do bear with me!

I am trying to upload an xml file to the FCA regdata website for Fund Data. in the xml files they supply as examples, they have the below:

```
<AIFReportingInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReportingMemberState="GB" Version="1.2" CreationDateAndTime="2021-07-30T15:50:53" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AIFMD_DATAIF_V1.2.xsd">
```

However, there are some technical issues on the Regdata upload site and they have put the below message on their website:

Firms should not include references to “xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation” within their files and should only include the schema reference:  xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

I have tried various deletions and changes, but I still get the same validation failure message error of schema not being correct.

I was wondering if anybody knew what the fix to the code is based on the limited guidance on their website, that I have included above?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, and Thank you Michael Kay for helping and editing the code. I have the solution here now for anyone else that may be looking for the same.

```
<AIFReportingInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReportingMemberState="GB" Version="1.2" CreationDateAndTime="2021-07-30T15:50:53">
```